# Changing the nth element of a list in a list changes the nth element of all lists in the list

Tags: python, list

I have a tictactoe program that first creates a gameplan where each row is a list containing an empty filler sign, which means the square is empty.

```
def createGamePlan(size, sign): 
    gPlan = []
    row = [sign]*size
    for i in range(size):
      gPlan.append(row)
    return gPlan
```

With a users choice of row and column I wish to update the sign of that specific element. So if i want to update the 1st column of the 2nd row to an "X" I would have

```
def updateGamePlan(row, col, gamePlan, sign):
    gamePlan[1][0] = "X"
```

This however changes the 1st column of **every single row** and I cant figure out why. I specify that its the 2nd row (1-th element of the gamePlan list, and the 0-th element of that inner list i.e the 1st column). Can someone point out what goes wrong and how I can, in the example above, only make it change the 1st column of the 2nd row, and not every row

Comment: I think you need to make a copy of the row: `gPlan.append(row[:])`

Comment: I'm sure there's a duplicate of this somewhere, but you're appending the same `row` in `gPlan`.

Comment: I don't think those are good targets, the issue there is `[[]]*n`, whereas here it's not the `*` operator...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial thing to understand is that `list` objects **do not have rows and columns**. List objects are ordered, heterogeneous sequences of objects. When you do:

```
def createGamePlan(size, sign): 
    gPlan = []
    row = [sign]*size
    for i in range(size):
      gPlan.append(row) # appends the SAME object
    return gPlan
```

So, consider the following:

```
>>> a = ['foo']
>>> bar = []
>>> for _ in range(4):
...     bar.append(a)
...
>>> [id(x) for x in bar]
[4534044744, 4534044744, 4534044744, 4534044744]
```

The objects are all the same!

```
>>> bar[0].append('baz')
>>> bar
[['foo', 'baz'], ['foo', 'baz'], ['foo', 'baz'], ['foo', 'baz']]
```

You create a list that contains *the same object* many times. A solution? Append a *copy*.

```
def createGamePlan(size, sign): 
    gPlan = []
    row = [sign]*size
    for i in range(size):
      gPlan.append(row.copy()) # appends a NEW object
    return gPlan
```

Be careful, though, because `.copy` only makes a *shallow* copy. Consider:

```
>>> row = [['foo'], ['bar']]
>>> grid = []
>>> for _ in range(5):
...     grid.append(row.copy())
...
>>> grid
[[['foo'], ['bar']], [['foo'], ['bar']], [['foo'], ['bar']], [['foo'], ['bar']], [['foo'], ['bar']]]
```

OK, swell! these are all independant objects!:

```
>>> [id(x) for x in grid]
[4534044616, 4534135432, 4534135560, 4534135176, 4534135688]
```

So... this should work fine, no?

```
>>> grid[0][0].append('baz')
>>> grid
[[['foo', 'baz'], ['bar']], [['foo', 'baz'], ['bar']], [['foo', 'baz'], ['bar']], [['foo', 'baz'], ['bar']], [['foo', 'baz'], ['bar']]]
```

What's going on? Well, a shallow copy created *new lists*, but not new *sublists*, i.e., it didn't copy any elements contained in the elements:

```
>>> [id(x) for row in grid for x in row]
[4534135048, 4534135112, 4534135048, 4534135112, 4534135048, 4534135112, 4534135048, 4534135112, 4534135048, 4534135112]
>>>
```

For that, you want a *deepcopy*:

```
>>> import copy
>>> row = [['foo'], ['bar']]
>>> grid = []
>>> for _ in range(5):
...     grid.append(copy.deepcopy(row))
...
>>> grid
[[['foo'], ['bar']], [['foo'], ['bar']], [['foo'], ['bar']], [['foo'], ['bar']], [['foo'], ['bar']]]
>>> [id(x) for row in grid for x in row]
[4534135432, 4534135368, 4534135176, 4534135880, 4534136328, 4534161928, 4534135112, 4534162120, 4534162248, 4534162184]
>>> grid[0][0].append('baz')
>>> grid
[[['foo', 'baz'], ['bar']], [['foo'], ['bar']], [['foo'], ['bar']], [['foo'], ['bar']], [['foo'], ['bar']]]
>>>
```